# How can I automate these CMD commands, so they can be ran together

Tags: command-line, cmd, terminal

I am writing automated ui tests for an Android application and after each change in the test code, I have to do the following:

```
e:
cd adt/sdk/tools/android create uitest-project -n TestAutomation -t 16 -p c:/Users/John/workspace/TestAutomation
c:
cd ../..
cd: Users/John/workspace/TestAutomation
ant build
adb push c:/Users/John/workspace/TestAutomation/bin/TestAutomation.jar /data/local/tmp/
adb shell uiautomator runtest TestAutomation.jar -c com.uia.example.my.TestApp
```

Is there a way I can configure those scripts to run by themselves together? Its a lot of typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
e:
cd \adt\sdk\tools\android create uitest-project -n TestAutomation -t 16 -p c:\Users\John\workspace\TestAutomation
c:
CD \Users\John\workspace\TestAutomation
CALL ant build
CALL adb push c:\Users\John\workspace\TestAutomation\bin\TestAutomation.jar \data\local\tmp\
CALL adb shell uiautomator runtest TestAutomation.jar -c com.uia.example.my.TestApp
GOTO :EOF
```

You should be able to simply save this file as *whatever.bat* and then simply execute *whatever*. Use an editor, not a word-processor.

Note that path-separators are `\`, not `/`

I've no idea what `adb` is - the `call` should execute it regardless of whether it is a batch or executable.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "instance=%~1"
if not defined instance set /p "instance=What instance ? "
if not defined instance echo no instance set&goto :eof
e:
cd \adt\sdk\tools\android create uitest-project -n %instance% -t 16 -p c:\Users\John\workspace\%instance%
c:
CD \Users\John\workspace\%instance%
CALL ant build
CALL adb push c:\Users\John\workspace\%instance%\bin\%instance%.jar \data\local\tmp\
CALL adb shell uiautomator runtest %instance%.jar -c com.uia.example.my.TestApp
GOTO :EOF
```

In this example, every mention of `TestAutomation` has been replaced by `%instance%`.

By running `*thisbatch* TestAutomation` then `instance` will be set to the value `TestAutomation` and substituted throughout.

By running `*thisbatch*` then `instance` will be set to *nothing* by the first `set` command (since there is no first parameter, `%1` - the added tilde means "and strip out any enclosing quotes") so it will be "not defined" and the `set/p` instruction allows the value to be input from the keyboard. If nothing is entered, then the procedure reports that and terminates.

Beyond that, follow the bouncing ball. %~2 would provide the second parameter to anothe variable if required for instance. Variables should start with a letter and contain alphanumerics+ a few special characters _#@$ and others - just don't get too clever. `%var%` accesses the value set. If you want spaces in a pathname, then "enclose the entire pathname in quotes"

Comment: Thank you I will test this and get back to you. adb is "Android Debug Bridge"

Comment: Ran like a charm! Thank you again! How can I introduce variables here, for example TestAutomation? And how can I concatenate the variable + ".jar" then?